# jQuery : How to use parents() with jquery object as parameter?

Tags: jquery

**Ok I have a jquery object held in a variable and I want to test if it is the parent of another object. Is that possible?**

```
var fatherElement= $('#fatherElement');

if($('#sonElement').parents(fatherElement).length>0){
alert('Luke I AM your father!');
}
```

Do you catch my drift?
Love some help on this lil' problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($('#sonElement').parents("#fatherElement").length > 0)
{
    alert('Luke I AM your father!');
}
```

`.partents` takes a selecor as the argument. If you only have the parent in a variable, you can use [`jQuery.contains`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/):

```
var fatherElement = $('#fatherElement').get();

if (jQuery.contains($('#sonElement').get(), fatherElement))
{
    alert('Luke I AM your father!');
}
```

`.get` simply gives us the DOM element of the jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this(searching if the sonElement exists in the fatherElement scope):

```
var fatherElement= $('#fatherElement'); 
if($('#sonElement', fatherElement).length>0){ 
    alert('Luke I AM your father!'); 
}
```

Comment: This looks great! Could you explain a little more how this works?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$.fn.hasParent = function(objs) {
    // ensure that objs is a jQuery array
    objs = $(objs); var found = false;
    $(this[0]).parents().andSelf().each(function() {
        if ($.inArray(this, objs) != -1) {
            found = true;
            return false; // stops the each...
        }
    });
    return found;
}
```

Reference: http://blog.bandit.co.nz/post/451104345/jquery-hasparent-function

Comment: You can later use this function as follows:
`$('#sonElement').hasParent($('#fatherElement'))`

Answer (score 0):

**Based on @Harpyon's answer this was my final solution:**

```
var parent = $('#fatherElement')[0];
var child = $('#sonElement')[0];
alert($.contains(parent,child));//alerts 'true' or 'false'
```